# Select .net control by string containing in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

I am working in asp.net and I have two imagebuttons like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Hosciz" ImageUrl="../image/ciz1.png" Width="20px"Height="20px" AlternateText="bla bla" />

<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Hosciz2" ImageUrl="../image/ciz1.png" Width="20px"Height="20px" AlternateText="bla bla again" />
```

Like you see both imagebutton ids contains 'Hosciz' string so I wonder can I use an .each() function with id containing. I know there is something like

```
$("div[id*='Hosciz']").each(function(){.....});
```

Is there a way to do this with imagebuttons or other .net controls instead of a html control like div ? I mean there sould be, but how ?

I know I can solve this like

```
$("#<%=Hosciz.ClientID%>").click(function(){ 'do whatever you want' });

$("#<%=Hosciz2.ClientID%>").click(function(){ 'do whatever you want' });
```

but like said I just wonder if there is a way to do this with each() function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class attribute on the image:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" CssClass="hosciz" ID="Hosciz" ImageUrl="../image/ciz1.png" Width="20px"Height="20px" AlternateText="bla bla" />
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" CssClass="hosciz" ID="Hosciz2" ImageUrl="../image/ciz1.png" Width="20px"Height="20px" AlternateText="bla bla again" />
```

and in jquery a class selector

```
$(".hosciz").each(function(){.....});
```

or

```
$("div.hosciz").each(function(){.....});
```

It has the added bonus of allowing you to a common style in css for the image.

Alternatively, use ClientIDMode="Static", to ensure your id in the html matches the asp ClisentID.  This does of course come with other problems - you'll need to make certain the ID is unique, but comes with a performance boost in the html selectors.

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  ID="Hosciz" ImageUrl="../image/ciz1.png" Width="20px"Height="20px" AlternateText="bla bla" />
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Hosciz2" ImageUrl="../image/ciz1.png" Width="20px"Height="20px" AlternateText="bla bla again" />
```

and in jquery,

```
$("#Hosciz, #Hosciz2").each(function(){.....});
```

Comment: I got more than I asked. Thank you ! :)